Numpy memmap corrupts array
I use numpy-2.1.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64. When I try to load an array via memmap, the array shape and data were corrupted. Minimum reproducible example is below:
>>> a = np.arange(65536)
>>> a
array([    0,     1,     2, ..., 65533, 65534, 65535])
>>> np.save('f.npy', a)

# When I load an array via np.load, it's OK.
>>> b = np.load('f.npy')
>>> b
array([    0,     1,     2, ..., 65533, 65534, 65535])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('int64')

# When I use memmap, the shape of array is corrupted and some elements were added into beginning
>>> c = np.memmap('f.npy', dtype=np.int64, mode='r')
>>> c
memmap([    379676406402707, 7166182912910098550, 4064846277420656498,
        ...,               65533,               65534,
                      65535])
>>> c.shape
(65552,)

# When I specified shape, the same elements were added into beginning, and elements on the tail were cropped.
>>> c = np.memmap('f.npy', dtype=np.int64, mode='r', shape=a.shape)
>>> c
memmap([    379676406402707, 7166182912910098550, 4064846277420656498,
        ...,               65517,               65518,
                      65519])

When I use np.load('f.npy', mmap_mode='r') in this example, it's ok, but in real data occures ValueError: Cannot load file containing pickled data when allow_pickle=False. If I toggle allow_pickle=True, then another error occurs: UnpicklingError: Failed to interpret file 'f.npy' as a pickle.
So, I want to use memmap. How can I do it correctly?

This is not a reproducable example since it doesnt reproduce the error. Did you save your data on a different python version? From the numpy save docs: Reasons for disallowing pickles include security and portability (pickled objects may not be loadable on different Python installations, for example if the stored objects require libraries that are not available, and not all pickled data is compatible between different versions of Python)

No, this example was executed in my machine with same version of Python, same version of numpy, in one console session. But this question is about the memmap, not about the pickles.

In the arange example, the npy file has a beginning buffer with shape, dtype, etc, followed by the data buffer.  I don't think that's supposed to be used directly with memmap.

@hpaulj, so, I must not mix (np.save/np.load) methods and (np.memmap write/read) methods, do I?

np.load has a mmap_mode option for this exact use case

If the file was created with np.save, only np.load can correctly load it, and if the file was created with np.memmap('f', mode='w+'), only np.memmap('f', mode='r') can open it?

You can use mmap_mode option of np.load, use arr.tofile to output without a header, or crop the first 128 bytes of the memmap.

You might make memmap work with a correct offset.  But that's just a guess.

There is a numpy.lib.format.open_memmap function.  np.load with memmap flag uses this. This function uses the normal load approach to read the header.  It gets an offset from that.  And then opens the file with memmap with this offset.

Files created by np.save and np.memmap are not compatible. File created by np.save has a header containing version, shape, data type and data order, but file created by np.memmap has not. When you read a file created by np.save via np.memmap, the file header will be in your array. In the source of numpy.lib.format.open_memmap function we can find that it firstly read the header from specified file, then creates memmap object with offset specified.
These 2 ways of save/load can be applied for numpy arrays:

Save and load via numpy load/save functions:

>>> a = np.arange(65536)
>>> np.save('f.npy', a)
>>> b = np.load('f.npy')
>>> b
array([    0,     1,     2, ..., 65533, 65534, 65535])
>>> b.shape
(65536,)
>>> c = np.load('f.npy', mmap_mode='r')
>>> c
memmap([    0,     1,     2, ..., 65533, 65534, 65535])
>>> c.shape
(65536,)


Save and load via memmap:

>>> a = np.arange(65536)
>>> outFile = np.memmap('f.npy', dtype=a.dtype, mode='w+', shape=a.shape)
>>> outFile[:] = a
>>> outFile.flush()
>>> inFile = np.memmap('f.npy', dtype=np.int64, mode='r')
>>> inFile
memmap([    0,     1,     2, ..., 65533, 65534, 65535])
>>> inFile.shape
(65536,)

When you mix these two ways, results will be corrupted.
